# Ito Isometry against non-Brownian SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, wiener-measure

Suppose $X_t$ is a Semi-martingale and $H_t$ is $X_t$-predictable.
I know that if $X_t=W_t$ is a Wiener process then
$$
\mathbb{E}[H\cdot W_T^2] = \mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_0^TH_t^2dt\bigg],
$$
where $H\cdot W_T$ denotes the stochastic integral of $H_t$ against $W_t$ up to time $T$.

My question is if $W_t$ is not a Weiner process then what is
$$
\mathbb{E}[H\cdot W_T^2]
$$
equal to?

Comment: It is then equal to $E[\int_0^TH_t^2d[X]_t]$ if $X_t$ is an $L^2$ martingale. Otherwise, no such isometry exists as far as I know.

Comment: Yes I need everything to be $L^2$.

Comment: Actually more importantly, the expectation you define with $X_t$ being a semi-martingale doesn't necessarily exist. So you need to cover that base before you think about isometries etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we assume that $X_t$ is $L^2$ and that $H_t$ is also $L^2$, in their respective senses then we may proceed as follows...

The result is again called the Ito isometry and given your setting is as follows:

### Itô Isometry

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(
\int_0^T H_t dX_t\right)^2
\right]
=
\mathbb{E}\left[
\int_0^T H_t^2 d[X]_t
\right],
$$
where $[X]_t$ denotes the quadratic variation of $X$.  Theorem 5 [in this blog shows the details of the result.](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/quadratic-variations-and-the-ito-isometry/)

In particular if $X_t$ is an Ito process, that is $X_t$ satisfies the SDE
$$
dX_t= \mu_tdt +\Sigma_tdW_t,
$$
then $[X_t]=\Sigma^{\star}\Sigma_t$.  In this case the Ito isomtery simplifies to

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(
\int_0^T H_t dX_t\right)^2
\right]
=
\mathbb{E}\left[
\int_0^T H_t^2 \Sigma^{\star}\Sigma dt
\right].  
$$
Hope this helped :)

Comment: This is incorrect as the Isometry result only applied if $X_t$ is a local Martingale without this condition, we don't have that $M_t^2-[M]_t$ is a Martingale (where $M_t = \int_0^T H_t dX_t$) and so its expectation is not $0$, and we don't have the Isometry. For a general SDE where the drift is not $0$ $X_t$, it is not a local martingale, and this result does not hold, at least not the one you have referenced, so this is incorrect and misleading; it might be worth retracting/editing.  I wasted a bit of time for first relying on this result, then checked and it was wrong :D ...